# iphone coredata xcdatamodel versioning...is their a limit to versions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, versioning, xcdatamodel

I am going through my 8th version of the iphone datamodel, and this is over the span of months, so improvements come along and changes have to be made. I was wondering if there is a limit to how many versions I end up creating.
Does this affect coredata performance?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit and it really doesn't affect performance as the version migration only happens once when a new version is introduced. Users will tolerate a one time lag right after they update an app.